# Android - support for multiple gamepads

Tags: android, gamepad

In my application I handle gamepad buttons with events :

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) 
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, final KeyEvent event)

int button = keyCode;
boolean isDown = event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
```

and axis events with

```
public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event)

float xaxis = event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_X);
float yaxis = event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_Y);
...
```

Currently does not depend how many gamepads are connected, everything works like when only one gamepad is connected.

For touch pointers is easy get values for every touch pointer :

```
MotionEvent event;
...
int index = event.getActionIndex();
int pointerID = event.getPointerId(index);
float x = event.getX(index);
float y = event.getY(index);
```

But how can I detect on which gamepad was f.e BUTTON_X pressed? and how can I detect to which gamepad belong axis events?

Thank you